# Enable-PSRemoting error: Cannot find any service with name 'winrm'

Tags: powershell, winrm, azure-runbook

I am running a powershell script in Azure Automation runbook. 
While executing `Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck - Force`, I get the error that there is no service named `winrm`.

Any idea what is the work around here?

Thanks

Comment: On the target computer check that the WinRM service is started and that Powershell is enabled in windows features and up to date. The Enable-PSRemoting cmdlet won't be available on early versions of Powershell.

Comment: if you would like execute powershell scritps on a remote azure vm from runbook, dont' need to use Enable-PSRemoting cmdlet, there is a built-in solution for that.

Comment: @IvanYang can you share any link or add some more information about that?

Comment: @cs_love, is this an azure vm? if yes, you can use [Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following as workarounds:

- [Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.13.0) from the AzureRM module, as @Ivan Yang pointed above (refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9044cbf4-d0de-4853-88df-b4b94b8badd4/how-to-remote-a-vm-using-azure-runbooks?forum=azureautomation) thread for more information)
- Additionally, you may also want to look into [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-automation-run-tasks-on-azure-virtual-machines-without-opening-ports/) solution that runs tasks on Azure VMs without opening ports or remoting, if that's what you're looking to accomplish.

Hope this helps.